# PostgreSQL: check if attribute is in table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm writing some triggers to check if an arrtibute of a newly create tuple is present in another table. What is the best way to check this?

```
IF (SELECT * FROM TABLEB where NEW.Attribute = Attribute) = NULL THEN
return NULL
END IF
```

Is there a better way? And does a Select that returns nothing = NULL or empty set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLEB where NEW.Attribute = Attribute)`.

An empty rowset isn't the same as `NULL`, which represents an empty cell of a row. Your syntax would only be valid if the query only selected one row, in which case PostgreSQL will allow use of comparison operators against the top cell returned, which counts as `NULL` if none are returned.